# Avoiding overriding variables when importing a subscript using dot notation

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

When I write complex PowerShell scripts, I use to split the scripts into separate files:

- `main.ps1` to contains the logic
- `imports\xxxx.ps1`, `imports\yyyy.ps1`, ... to provides custom functions

The `main.ps1` file imports in the current scope the functions using the dot command after having computed the path relative to the current directory. Ex:

```
$CurrentDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

. "$CurrentDirectory\Imports\Maths.ps1"

Process-Multiply -x 10 -y 10 # assuming there's a function in the maths.ps1
```

This is working as long as I don't overwrite the variables within the imported scripts. For example, if my subscripts again declare a `$CurrentDirectory` variable, it actually overwrite the variable from the main script. I guess it's because of the dot notation (in opposition to the & notation).

Is there a way to avoid this ? Is it possible to have "local" variable for a script ?

Here's a full reproductible sample:

File `main.ps1` :

```
$CurrentDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

Write-Host "`$CurrentDirectory from main.ps1 : $CurrentDirectory"

. "$CurrentDirectory\Imports\Maths.ps1"

Write-Host "`$CurrentDirectory from main.ps1 : $CurrentDirectory"

Process-Multiply -x 10 -y 10
```

File `Imports\Maths.ps1` :

```
$CurrentDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

function Process-Multiply{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$x,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$y
    )

    $x * $y
}
```

When running the main.ps1 script, the output is :

```
$CurrentDirectory from main.ps1 : C:\temp\xx 
$CurrentDirectory from main.ps1 : C:\temp\xx\Imports 
100
```

As you can see, the `$CurrentDirectory` variable is overriden in the sub script.

---

PS: I know I could rename the variable in the subscript, but in a larger scope with centralized scripts, it would be hard to ensure uniqueness of variable names.

PPS: the real world scenario where I need directory path of current script is to load a custom module from a c# assembly. The assembly is located in a subdirectory of a loader script.

PPPS (!) : I have to stick to PS v4

Comment: When dot-sourcing and using the exact same variable names as in the main script you indeed overwrite the value. If in the secondary script you use this variable only intended as being local to that script, why not choose a different variable name for it?

Comment: As I said, in simple scenario it would be possible. But we have built a complex ecosystem of scripts that can be included on demand, per usage. It would be very risky to rely on variable names uniqueness. One day or another, a developer may override a variable name, or use a name that will be overriden without seeing it immediately

Comment: In my opinion dotsourcing in a complex ecosystem of scripts is not a good combination. My recommendation would be to write functions that have own/local variables by nature and group your functionality (a) module(s)

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld: can a module be loaded from a folder instead of the `$Pshome\modules` folder ? I see the `-Assembly` param but not `-Path` or similar (in order to enable copy/pasting zip with everything required from environement to environnement)

Comment: I think I answered myself [`Import-Module -Name c:\ps-test\modules\test -Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-6#examples)

Comment: @SteveB I am not sure if all kinds of modules can be loaded from a folder of choice. I do it al lot with simple .psm1 script modules though.

Comment: Functions inside modules, you'll have no issues with variables being overwritten. If you have all the modules in a central location, you can add it to the [`PSModulesPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path). Then if the modules 'exported commands' are setup correctly, PowerShell will load your functions from within modules when you reference/call them - you don't need to _explicitly_ use Import-Module for each module dependency this way - for PS v3+.